# Why does Django's built-in "url" tag cause an error when running unit tests?

Tags: django, django-templates

In my Django templates, I have a couple pieces of code that are like this:

```
<a href="{% url root %}">Root</a>
```

They work properly when rendering the template. However, whenever I run my unit tests using Django's unit testing framework, I get the following error:

> NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'mysite.root' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

The root is named properly in `urls.py` (`url(r'^$', 'index', name='root')`) and, again, the error doesn't show up when browsing the site -- only during unit tests.

If I change the code to this:

```
{% url root as root_path %}
<a href="{{ root_path }}">Root</a>
```

the error also goes away. What's the problem with the first piece of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently, the tests were actually failing because Django couldn't find a Site record in the database. It may be because my `SITE_ID` is set to something other than 1; this was supposedly fixed, as mentioned in this [ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5979), but it doesn't seem to be actually fixed.